Histogram with horizontal gradient fill only over set limit
I am trying to apply a gradient on a histogram based on how high the values in a data frame are. The gradient however should only start after a set level of concern, meaning that any values below this level of concern will remain solid green and all the values above said level should gradually go from green to red, indicating how much higher than the level the values are.
I have been able to apply the gradient but I'm unsure of how to apply the condition.
Here's a MWE. Any help would be appreciated.
What I have:

What I need:

library(ggplot2)

# Level of concern
loc = 0.4

set.seed(1234)
mydata <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1000), b = rnorm(1000)/2)


ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = a, fill = ..x..)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkgreen", high = "red")


You can use scale_fill_gradientn by controlling the parameters values and limits to achieve such an effect.
# Control the colour positions
colourControl <- c(0, 0.5, 1)

# Create histogram
ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x = a, fill = ..x..)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("darkgreen", "darkgreen", "red"), values = colourControl,
                       limits = range(mydata$a))  

In the picture below you see that the gradient only starts around 0. Note that values are in proportions of the limits.


Thank you! Is there a way to add a line at the level of concern (at 0.4 in this case) to better display the transition?

After choosing colourControl  so that the gradient actually starts at 0.4 instead of 0 in my case, you can use geom_vline(xintercept = loc). mean(mydata$a < loc) can help you finding the right value for the start of the transition.
